# Потокобезопасность static полей

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, .net-core

Всегда думал, что доступ к статик полю с целю модификации из разных потоков приводит к undefined behavior, но оказалось что это не так.

В тестовых целях написал следующее

```
static class StaticTest
{
    public static XClass X = new XClass();

    internal class XClass
    {
        public int Count;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, 5)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(_ => 
                new Thread(() => 
                { 
                    resetEvent.WaitOne(); 
                    StaticTest.X.Count++;
                })
                    .Start()); 

        resetEvent.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(StaticTest.X.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Пробовал так же Parallel.Invoke, все варианты в итоге дали 5.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы вместо 5 впишите хотя бы 1000. Ну чтобы гонка потоков была более выражена.

Comment: У меня уже на 500 выдало 493, даже с ожиданием в 10 секунд. Другими словами там никакой безопасности нет, сплошная опасность.

Comment: Проблема в непонимании проблем многопоточности. Такие проблемы тем и коварны, что проявляются не каждый раз и что их появление зависит от многих факторов.

Comment: Поставьте к примеру не 5, а 500, и сравните `StaticTest.X.Count++` с `Interlocked.Increment(ref StaticTest.X.Count)`. Первый даст вам с очень большой вероятностью значение 460-499, второй - всегда 500. То есть обеспечение атомарности операции инкремента лечит всю эту историю, следовательно, вопрос не имеет отношения к `static`, а только к потокобезопасности при обращении к `int` полю `X`. Совершенно все равно где поле `X` при этом будет находиться, оно может быть даже не полем, а локальной переменной, ничего от этого не изменится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. 
Про Interlocked.Increment знаю, про то что никакой потокобезопаности там из коробки нет, тоже.
На 1000 потоках, действительно на пару запусках было значение отличное от 1000 (998, 999).
Но почему так, все равно не совсем ясно.
Я предполагал что одновременный запуск 5-ти потоков приведет к чтению текущего значения (0) и в итоге почти гарантированно буду иметь большое количество тестов с результатами отличными от 5. 
А как оказалось даже запуск 1000 потоков, не всегда дает "странное" поведение

Comment: `не всегда дает "странное" поведение` - это и есть вся суть непредсказуемости поведения.